# Replace same non-alphanumberic character in re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

I am using `\W{}\W.format(sigs)` to find out some variables and replace them with something else. After replacement, I want to restore the same non-alphanumeric characters which existed earlier.

When I do this:

```
sigs = 'v__a'
CondStr = "(1 & v__a) == 0"
CondStr = re.sub("\W{}\W".format(sigs), "\Wz3Sigs\W", CondStr)
print CondStr
```

As expected I get output as `(1 &\Wz3Sigs\W == 0`, while actually I want output as `(1 & z3Sigs) == 0`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What would be your expected output for : `CondStr = "(1 & v_+a) == 0"`?

Comment: There shouldn't be any replacement if nothing in `sigs` matches. So, in above case there shouldn't be any replacement. `sigs` is a list in actual program

Comment: Then you can simply use `str.replace` here: `CondStr.replace(sigs,"z3Sigs")`

Comment: problem with replace is that I have both `v__a` and `v__v__a` in my expressions and I don't want any replacement to happen in second when I want to change the first variable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

`CondStr2 = re.sub("(\W){0}(\W)".format(sigs), r"\1z3Sigs\2", CondStr)`

Output

```
>>> CondStr
'(1 & v__a) == 0'
>>> CondStr2
'(1 & z3Sigs) == 0'
```

You group the `\W` separators and then just put them back. Remeber to make the replacement string "raw" by using `r''`, otherwise the replacement `\` will be escaped

Answer (score 0):

The special sequence `\b` is suitable.

```
CondStr = re.sub(r"\b{0}\b".format(sigs), "z3Sigs", CondStr)
```